# WebGL with WWW::Mechanize::Chrome (and others)

Tags: google-chrome, perl, headless, firefox-marionette

I need to run an automated process accessing WebGL inside an iFrame - headless, and after a login.

Up until now I've attempted to do this in different ways:

- Firefox::Marionette which fails because it doesn't support WebGL
- WWW::Mechanize::Chrome which fails if I attempt to run it headless (but works like a charm on non-headless)
- WWW::Mechanize::Chrome via xvfb-run - which fails with "No executable like '/usr/bin/xvfb-run -a --server-args="-screen 0 1280x800x24 -ac -nolisten tcp -dpi 96 +extension RANDR" /usr/bin/google-chrome'

The latter is run like this:

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Chrome->new(
                       headless => 0,
                       launch_exe => '/usr/bin/xvfb-run -a --server-args="-screen 0 1280x800x24 -ac -nolisten tcp -dpi 96 +extension RANDR" /usr/bin/google-chrome',
                       launch_arg => ["--headless" , "--no-sandbox"],
                      );
```

Is there something I haven't tried that could work? I am using perl - but might grudgingly try Python if there's a chance it will work.

Comment: WebGL is JavaScript I think so Selenium may work?  I use Selenium::Chrome (or ::Firefox) where yuo don't need to mess with servers etc.  (Never tried WebGL, this is a guess.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xvfb-run` must be prepended to the perl script like this

```
/usr/bin/xvfb-run -a --server-args="-screen 0 1280x800x24 \
    -ac -nolisten tcp -dpi 96 +extension RANDR" \
    perl chrome_script.pl
```

so it wraps the script, and the chrome instance inside it.

See the [manual for xvfb-run](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/xvfb-run.1.html)

Answer (score 0):

I've added [some documentation](https://github.com/david-dick/firefox-marionette#webgl) to show how to get WebGL working with Firefox::Marionette if you're still interested.  Specifically you need to initialise like so;

```
my $firefox = Firefox::Marionette->new( addons => 1, visible => 1 );
```